# Importing Crypto Modules in Haskell

Tags: haskell, module

I am trying to run some haskell files, I have never done haskell by the way before and i am running into an error.

```
import Crypto.Types.PubKey.ECDSA (Signature(..), PrivateKey(..), PublicKey(..))
import Crypto.Types.PubKey.ECC (Curve(CurveFP), CurvePrime(..), CurveCommon(..), Point(..))

import Codec.Crypto.ECC.Base (modinv)

import Crypto.Random (genBytes, GenError, CryptoRandomGen)
import Crypto.Util (bs2i, i2bs, i2bs_unsized)

import ECDSA.Util

Could not find module ‘Crypto.Types.PubKey.ECC’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

How do i import/install these modules? Thanks.

An output of ghc-pkg list

```
 Cabal-2.0.0.2
    GLURaw-2.0.0.3
    GLUT-2.7.0.12
    HTTP-4000.3.7
    HUnit-1.6.0.0
    ObjectName-1.1.0.1
    OpenGL-3.0.2.0
    OpenGLRaw-3.2.5.0
    QuickCheck-2.10.0.1
    StateVar-1.1.0.4
    array-0.5.2.0
    async-2.1.1.1
    attoparsec-0.13.2.0
    base-4.10.0.0
    binary-0.8.5.1
    bytestring-0.10.8.2
    call-stack-0.1.0
    case-insensitive-1.2.0.10
    containers-0.5.10.2
    deepseq-1.4.3.0
    directory-1.3.0.2
    fgl-5.6.0.0
    filepath-1.4.1.2
    fixed-0.2.1.1
    ghc-8.2.1
    ghc-boot-8.2.1
    ghc-boot-th-8.2.1
    ghc-compact-0.1.0.0
    ghc-prim-0.5.1.0
    ghci-8.2.1
    half-0.2.2.3
    hashable-1.2.6.1
    haskeline-0.7.4.0
    haskell-src-1.0.2.0
    hoopl-3.10.2.2
    hpc-0.6.0.3
    hscolour-1.24.1
    html-1.0.1.2
    integer-gmp-1.0.1.0
    integer-logarithms-1.0.2
    mtl-2.2.1
    network-2.6.3.2
    network-uri-2.6.1.0
    parallel-3.2.1.1
    parsec-3.1.11
    pretty-1.1.3.3
    primitive-0.6.2.0
    process-1.6.1.0
    random-1.1
    regex-base-0.93.2
    regex-compat-0.95.1
    regex-posix-0.95.2
    rts-1.0
    scientific-0.3.5.1
    split-0.2.3.2
    stm-2.4.4.1
    syb-0.7
    template-haskell-2.12.0.0
    terminfo-0.4.1.0
    text-1.2.2.2
    tf-random-0.5
    time-1.8.0.2
    transformers-0.5.2.0
    unix-2.7.2.2
    unordered-containers-0.2.8.0
    vector-0.12.0.1
    xhtml-3000.2.2
    zlib-0.6.1.2


name:            ecdsa
version:         0.2
cabal-version:   >= 1.8
license:         OtherLicense
license-file:    COPYING
category:        Crypto
copyright:       © 2014 Stephen Paul Weber
author:          Stephen Paul Weber <singpolyma@singpolyma.net>
maintainer:      Stephen Paul Weber <singpolyma@singpolyma.net>
stability:       experimental
tested-with:     GHC == 7.4.1
synopsis:        Basic ECDSA signing implementation
homepage:        https://github.com/singpolyma/ecdsa-haskell
bug-reports:     https://github.com/singpolyma/ecdsa-haskell/issues
build-type:      Simple
description:
        Wraps the stuff in hecc to do ECDSA.

extra-source-files:
        README

library
        exposed-modules:
                ECDSA

        other-modules:
                ECDSA.Util

        build-depends:
                base == 4.*,
                bytestring,
                hecc,
                crypto-pubkey-types,
                crypto-api

source-repository head
        type:     git
        location: git://github.com/singpolyma/ecdsa-haskell.git
```

This is the .cabal file, and i downloaded this project from this github link to try to understand it

https://github.com/singpolyma/ecdsa-haskell

Comment: can you tell us more about your setup - do you use `stack` or `cabal` do you have a single file or a project? what `ghc`-version do you use, what version of `stack` and `cabal`? Can you show the output of `ghc-pkg list`?

Comment: hello @epsilonhalbe I went to https://www.haskell.org/downloads and i downloaded the "Haskell Platform: Installs GHC, Cabal, and some other tools, along with a starter set of libraries in a global location on your system". I also use stack version 1.5.1. Its a project, and i am using the Sublime Text IDE. I edited the post to show the output of ghc-pkg list

Comment: if you use a project you have to add `the-library` to your `build-depends` section in your `.cabal`-file. Which library - I don't know but `stack build`should give you a good guess what to add.

Comment: please show me the contents of your `.cabal`-file then I can help you a little bit more. (also don't post pictures of your terminal output, but rather include the text, such that the question is self contained, if the pic is removed from whatever platform, nobody reading this in a few years will understand what this is about.)

Comment: Hello @epsilonhalbe, I will be editing my posts in a few minutes. This is my first time trying out haskell, so i apologize for the little questions that i am asking that i should already have the answer to

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build the package but it requires llvm-3.9 to work, which for some reason does not in my setup.

Also the package `hecc` is deprecated - and the git repo is 4 years old, quite outdated. if you use this for production purposes I would strongly discourage you from doing that.

Here is a `stack.yaml` which should probably work, but `hF2`+`llvm` keeps bugging me as I said before.

### `stack.yaml`

```
resolver: nightly-2017-10-28
packages:
- .
extra-deps:
- hF2-0.2
- hecc-0.4.1.1
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
```

try to build with `stack build`

Comment: hello @epsilonhalbe i am not at home right now, but once i get home, i will take your corrections and work on it. Just to be sure, i shouldn't change the .cabal file? just the stack.yaml file? I am definitely not using this for production, i will just like to see it run so i can understand what it is doing and step through each line of code. Thanks for the advice